# Boot from different startup disk AND in safe or recovery mode

Tags: startup

I have two versions of Mac OS on my mac pro: Mojave, and 10.8.5.

While using Mojave, I selected the startup disk to the other one via Preference Pane in order to access some old programs.

To switch back to Mojave, I tried the same thing, but 10.8 doesn’t recognise the volume where Mojave is (I imagine due to the new file system), so the option doesn’t even show up in 10.8’s Startup Disk preferences.

I thought - no problems, I’ll do it while booting, by pressing OPTION. The startup disk selection screen appears correctly. However, after I select Mojave this way, the loading screen gets stuck.

So what I would need to do is  (1) press OPTION during startup to select Mojave as the boot disk, AND (2) launch safe (or recovery mode) while that one is booting. However I haven’t figured out a way to do this. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question seems confusing. Are you trying to boot to recovery mode? If so, which recovery mode? Mojave or 10.8.5?

Comment: I’ve updated the text to make it clearer, but long story short, i’m stuck in 10.8. I need to boot (in safe or recovery mode) using MOJAVE.

Answer (score 1):

The [rEFInd Boot Manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) will allow you to select to boot from a recovery volume.

Use the following steps to install rEFInd.

1. Boot back to OS X 10.8.5.
2. Download  [rEFInd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/).
3. Assuming you have downloaded [rEFInd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) to your `Downloads` folder,  you can install rEFInd by entering the following commands in a Terminal application window.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.11.4
   sudo ./refind-install
   ```
4. Restart your Mac.
5. From options shown on the rEFInd menu, select to boot from a recover volume.

If you change the default so the Mac no longer boots to rEFInd, then following commands can be entered from OS X 10.8.5 to change the default back to rEFInd.

```
cd ~
mkdir efi
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 efi
sudo bless --mount efi --setBoot --file efi/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi --shortform
sudo umount efi
rmdir efi
```

rEFInd can be removed by using the following commands.

```
cd ~
mkdir efi
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 efi
cd efi/EFI
rm -r refind tools
cd ~
sudo umount efi
rmdir efi
```

Comment: I can not completely replicate your configuration of 10.8.5 and Mojave. Therefore, I could  not test this procedure completely. Let me know if you have any problems.